# Why angular app with embedded app throws an error Runtime compiler is not loaded in AOT mode?

Tags: angular, gwt, angular-aot, angular-jit

I'm using an old gwt application in angular app. I had no better idea than past gwt app into assets dir and specify script with entry point in index.html In dev mode everything works well that's why I didn't suspect any bad thing. But after build --prod...

```
Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
```

This gwt app is a standalone app which download and run .js files, localization files, styles. I tried to mention file with entry point in angular.json 'scripts' section. The same error. Also i tried to implement the tip from comment [Angular AoT and Rollup - Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310846/angular-aot-and-rollup-error-runtime-compiler-is-not-loaded#comment75653142_44310846)
This app is also creates canvas tag. May be this leads to the problem.

```
export function createJitCompiler() {
  return new JitCompilerFactory().createCompiler([{useJit: true}]);
}
```

Also the same result. I don't much expect that somebody had this strange case. But I think if app works good in dev mode, then there is a way to work in prod. And somebody knows how. Thanks